# Embedded Linux - replacing symbolic linked file not updating

Tags: symlink

I am troubleshooting an embedded Linux system. There is a program, let's call it `foo`. It is symlinked to a super program, let's call it `bar`, similar to `busybox`.

```
#ls -l foo
lrwxrwxrwx .... foo -> bar
```

I want to troubleshoot `foo` but I cannot replace `bar` because it is used by many. Not to mention it is always giving me "file busy" when I try to replace it.

So I tried replacing `foo` only. However, despite verifying that my copy of `foo` is being installed, there is no more symlink, and all running copy of `foo` has been killed and respawned, it is still the same old `bar` standing in for `foo`.

How can I get around this?